# Why we should check for the variable being defined var m = m || function(){}

Tags: javascript

Lot of libraries i have seen methods defined like this

```
Common.deepCopy = Common.deepCopy || function(oldObject) {
        return $.extend(true, {}, oldObject);
    };
```

What is the need of defining methods are objects like this.

Because the js files will be executed only once so there is no chance of deepCopy being defined previously.

Comment: What if another library implements that exact method? Then the check makes sense, imo..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not always the case. You never know whether the JS file is included twice or whether it is initialized again. Better to check whether the object exists and assign it if it does. Otherwise create a new object

Answer (score 3):

It's just in case it's already been defined in another file, or if the script runs more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Often this is to check if something already exists in the environment or not, like `Array.prototype.indexOf`.  It doesn't exist in oldIE.

```
var indexOf = [].indexOf ? fn : fn2
```

Now you could define fn to use the native indexOf and then use fn2 for environments that don't support it.

It's better this way so you don't have to check every time you call the function--instead you check when you define it.